# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: exports with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs

This is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

This is some tsx file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function Panel() {
    return (
        <span>Panel test</span>
    )
}

export default Panel
```

I run

```
npx tsc
npm start
```

And get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: exports
```

Comment: did you try setting `"jsx":"react"`?

Comment: I would expand on the previous comment  from @ravi-yadav try `"jsx": "react-jsx"` also add `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` and see if that fixes it

Comment: you by mistake used exports in place of export in any file. try searching exports and change it to export